# Django generic Views with templates

Tags: django-templates, django-views

I've added a new template to my project (thing_listings.html) and I've added the views;

```
from django.views import generic
from .models import Things

class IndexView(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'home/index.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Things.objects.all()

**class ThingView(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'home/thing_listings.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Things.objects.all()**

class DetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Labs
    template_name = 'home/detail.html'
```

and the URl's;

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

app_name = 'home'

urlpatterns = [
    # /home/
    url(r'^$', views.IndexView.as_view(), name = 'index'),
    **# /thingview/
    url(r'^$', views.ThingView.as_view(), name='thingview'),**
    # /home/"details"/
    url(r'^(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.DetailView.as_view(), name='detail'),
]
```

At the moment the site runs fine, except when I click on the thing_listings link I just get directed to index instead of what thing view is supposed to direct me to. Please help, I'm not sure where I've gone wrong.

Ive used the href: {% url 'home:thingview' %}

Comment: Is the `**` in front of the class `ThingView` intentional?

Comment: No it's not, I was trying to make those lines bold, as that is the relative code to the issue.
I should probably also add that I've tried to use generic.TemplateView instead of generic.ListView I wasn't sure if they would be overwriting each other or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution if anyone else is having the same issue.

All you should need to do is add the path to your regular expression eg:

```
url(r'^servicesview/$', views.ServicesView.as_view(), name='services'),
```

I've repeated the process multiple times to make sure it works.